# find: paths must precede expression:

Tags: find

I found the following line [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/97763/linux-gzip-multiple-subdirectories-into-separate-archives):

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec tar czvf {}.tar.gz {} \; \;
```

It is meant to tar gzip each folder in the current directory individually. But running it returns the error:

```
find: paths must precede expression:
```

There are a few posts on this error, but they don't relate to the syntax used here.

Does anyone know what is causing this error?

Comment: Where did you find it? The {} in front of tar.gz seem odd to me. I would assume { and } are not valid chars when creating a file (unless you put the name in between backticks/double qoutes).

Comment: Posted AU thread above.

Comment: @Rinzwind `{}` in an `-exec` expression is expanded (by `find`, not by the shell) to the name of each file found. See [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/find.1.html) for details. (It's common to see `\{\}` or `'{}'`. In some expressions, `{}` has to be quoted to prevent actual or attempted shell expansion of it before it's passed to `find`. But `{}` doesn't need to be quoted as it's used in this question. For example, `find . -maxdepth 1 -exec echo {}.blah \;` works fine from `bash`.) As [muru says](http://askubuntu.com/a/515245), the problem here is instead the extra `\;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this out, and the error is due to the second `\;`:

```
# Works fine
find * -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec tar czvf {}.tar.gz {} \;
# Errors out
find * -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec tar czvf {}.tar.gz {} \; \;
```

This might because the first escaped `;` ends the command for the `-exec` option, and the second escaped `;` now becomes part of the the `find` command, and is treated as a path. This throws an error since the `-type` expression has already been read.